# How to solve the pty master write slave read. Master write the data master will also read?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pty

```
void epoll_func(epoll_event event){
char str[BUFSIZE] = {'\0'};
int c =0; 

if(event.data.fd ==  connfd && EPOLLIN){
    while(true){
        c = read( connfd, str, BUFSIZE);

        write( 1, str, c); 
        if(c<BUFSIZE)
            break;
    }   
}else if( event.data.fd == 0 && EPOLLIN ){
    while(true){
        c = read( 0, str, BUFSIZE);

        send( connfd, str, c, 0); 
        if(c<BUFSIZE)
            break;
    }   
}
```

}

Write data to the master, but also read the data to write their own. How to do?

thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like C. Why spamming the C++ tag?

Comment: `0 && EPOLLIN` can be expressed much simpler ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up the epoll_event structure you get which consists of an event field and a `union` containing the data. I suppose you want to do something like the following:

```
struct epoll_event e;

uint32_t e_type = e.events;
int fd = e.data.fd;

if (fd == myfd) {
   if (events && EPOLLIN)) {
      /* my watched fd and can be read from */
   }
   if (events && EPOLLOUT) {
      /* my watched fd and can be written to */
   }
}
```